# NDMP Daemon for debian

Tags: linux, backup

I'm looking for an open source which implement NDMP protocol in Debian, but not successful yet. I tried to install and run NDMP SDK (https://code.google.com/p/ndmp4linux/downloads/detail?name=ndmpkit.v3.2.tar.gz), ndmjob, opendmp, ndmfs, but some of these tools can not be installed in Debian (NDMP SDK), the other running with error when I use ndmpcopy tool to copy between two volume. So, is there any open source tool which implement NDMP protocol running successful in Debian

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use [Bareos](https://github.com/bareos/bareos/blob/master/README.NDMP) for that. You can install the dummy package  `bareos` via apt-get, and that will pull in with it the `bareos-storage` package, which should include support for NDMP.

Comment: I tried to use BareOS for many times, but it does not success. I got many errors, and after that, I found out BareOS use ndmjob for its NDMP function. I also tried to run ndmjob, but it does not success too.